# Did Alan Rickman research Spock and/or Leonard Nimoy for Galaxy Quest?

Tags: star-trek, actors, spock, galaxy-quest

[image: Galaxy Quest crew]

In *Galaxy Quest*, Alan Rickman plays fictional actor Alexander Dane, who in turn became famous for playing an alien science officer — Dr. Lazarus — on television.  Not relishing his role as Lazarus, Dane is annoyed by the fame he has achieved and the types of fans who adore him.

Given the parallels between *Galaxy Quest* and *Star Trek*, both in and out of universe, Lazarus is clearly a reference to Spock and Dane to Leonard Nimoy.

**Is there any evidence that Rickman had researched Spock's character and/or Leonard Nimoy's acting and feelings about Spock while preparing to play Dane?**

Comment: Apropos something: Shatner being Shatner: `I thought it was very funny, and I thought the audience that they portrayed was totally real, but the actors that they were pretending to be were totally unrecognizable. Certainly I don't know what Tim Allen was doing. He seemed to be the head of a group of actors, and for the life of me I was trying to understand who he was imitating. The only one I recognized was the girl playing Nichelle Nichols`

Comment: @DVK : Lol, awesome quote!

Comment: @Praxis - lol, yeah, the image of the title appears like its one word, but I think they were just retro-fiying the title font for visual effect.

Comment: @Praxis:   On the other hand, I was pretty surprised find there are ***no*** other questions that appear to qualify for this tag.   Clearly you need to go ask 14 other [tag:galaxy-quest] questions!

Comment: Actually, it occurred to me recently that Rickman's turn as Dane bore more resemblance to how Sir Alec Guinness felt about playing Obi-Wan Kenobi than anything Nimoy ever really felt about playing Spock (even in his "I Am Not Spock" years). Sir Alec **hated** everything about working on Star Wars and proposed Kenobi's death himself so he wouldn't have "...to say any more of those bloody awful banal lines...."

Comment: @UncleMikey: Very true.  But the overall structure is very Star Trek, as is the alien science officer aspect. That being said, if you can find evidence that Rickman based his performance more with Guinness in mind that would be an answer.

Comment: @Praxis - Rickman said he based the performance on himself (as in, he was playing himself). Sorry, couldn't find anything about Nimoy so far.

Comment: @DVK: That's an answer, in my opinion!  :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He never mentioned Spock or Nimoy in any interviews I found. But it seems that he based the character on **himself**, in part.

> I did grow up, as it were, inside the Royal Sheakspeare Company, and other, similar environments, so I know what he's going through, on some level....
>
> I remember, when Sigourney and I were sitting at an autograph table at the convention, and I remember saying: "This is a bit too close for comfort"...
>
> There were certain images and moments where you just thought: "I've lived this"
>
> (*"Alan Rickman Galaxy Quest documentary"*)